# request for xamarin forms count down timer?

Tags: c#, timer, xamarin.forms, countdowntimer

i want to create a count down timer for xamarin forms that output for all platform(android,Ios,wp....)like this picture.i like to use it without any library or dependency or etc.and it has view layout too[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J8Jxq.png)

Comment: I am sorry but I am voting this to close. There seems to be no effort on your part and the question is fairly simple to do. But we are not going to do it for you, sorry. Please read [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) on how to ask a proper question.

Comment: you just only get me a negative point for this sir?i search in every where but no answer for this MR Fullstack

Answer (score 2):

Use this **method** on your **constructor** of class that extends from Page classes like *ContentPage*.

```
private async void ShowingTimer()
    {

            int _end = 0;
            for (int _minute = 1; _minute >= 0; _minute--)
            {
                for (int _second = 59; _second >= 0; _second--)
                {
                    if (_second < 10)
                        {
                            _secondView.Text = Convert.ToString("0" + _second);
                        }
                    else
                        {   
                            _secondView.Text = Convert.ToString(_second);
                        }
                        _minuteView.Text = Convert.ToString("0" + _minute);
                        await Task.Delay(1000);
                }
                _end++;
            if (_end == 2) {break;}
            }

    }
```

and this code for **layout** in **xaml** :

```
<Grid>
 <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
  <ColumnDefinition Width="25*"/>
  <ColumnDefinition Width="20*"/>
  <ColumnDefinition Width="5*"/>
  <ColumnDefinition Width="25*"/>
  <ColumnDefinition Width="25*"/>   
 </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
   <Grid Grid.Column="0"/>
   <Label Grid.Column="1" x:Name="_minuteView"   VerticalOptions="Fill"HorizontalOptions="Fill" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" FontSize="35"/>
   <Label Grid.Column="2" Text=" : " FontSize="25" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"/>
   <Label Grid.Column="3" x:Name="_secondView" VerticalOptions="Fill" HorizontalOptions="Fill" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" FontSize="35"/>
   <Grid Grid.Column="4"/>
</Grid>
```